# Métodos para grabar videos en Android

Tags: android, array, video, byte

En internet he encontrado dos maneras de grabar videos en Android una es usando Intent y la otra usando Media Recorder, ambas devuelven un fichero de salida con la información en él, pero lo q necesito es poder manipular esa información primero antes de que llegue al fichero de salida. Por lo tanto mi pregunta es si existe algún otro método para grabar videos en Android Studio que me permita utilizar la información como arreglo de bytes antes de que llegue a un fichero d salida, o si hay alguna forma de manipular los antes mencionados para lograr esto. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usando un glsurfaceview este necesita un renderer, el renderer tiene la funcion drawFrame, donde tienes que dibujar el preview o guardar el frame (grabar).

Para mostrar el preview es sencillo creas un texture opengl, con eso crear un surfacetexture que es lo que necesita la camara, luego dibujas el texture te da un id al crear, con el mismo dibujas.

Para grabar tienes que tener un codificador que en android esta el MediaCodec con el creas tu surface.
Create un windowssurface con egl tienes que pasarle el surface del MediaCodec, egl es el que proporciona como una panel o lienzo donde dibuja opengl.

Ya solo cuando le de grabar pones el windowssurface que creaste como actual y empiezas a dibujar la textura del preview con su id usando opengl.

luego de dibujar, con el objeto mediacodec puedes obtener el buffer de salida, es un array de bytes, cada que dibujas un frame llamas a obtener el buffer de salida, con esos bytes puedes escribir en el disko, La mas usada es MediaMuxer para combinar grafico con sonido, igual sirve sin sonido.

Aqui tienes ejemplos:

(Si quieres poner overlay camera view tiene esa opción)
https://github.com/natario1/CameraView

https://github.com/google/grafika